# How to read returned stream data

Tags: vb.net

I am currently reading a stream like this:

```
 wc = New System.Net.WebClient()
 strm = wc.OpenRead(url)
 Data.ReadXml(strm, XmlReadMode.InferSchema)
 strm.Close()
```

Besides the Dataset reading the stream I would also like to be able to output the text to the log file. Or for testing to a debug.print statement.

How can I do that? I have tried adding a new stream reader after the wc.openread but then there is no data for the dataset to read.
Any help would be appreciated..
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the

```
Data.ReadXml(strm, XmlReadMode.InferSchema)
```

call the **Data.GetXml**

```
Dim xmlString As String = Data.GetXml
```

Sample below,

```
    Dim Data As New DataSet
    Using wc = New System.Net.WebClient()
        Using strm = wc.OpenRead("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment")
            Data.ReadXml(strm, XmlReadMode.InferSchema)
            Dim xmlString As String = Data.GetXml
            Debug.WriteLine(xmlString)
        End Using
    End Using
```